# How to disregard a negative value in a set of input

Tags: c

I'd like to ask what should I do (don't tell the exact code) to disregard a negative value if I were to add 5 integers. For example, I have inputted 1, 2, 3, 4, and -1. The sum should be 10 not 9 since it is required to disregard the negative values. Thank you in advance!

```
int main()
{
int num, sum=0, i;

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
printf("Please enter 5 integers: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
sum+=num;
}
printf("The sum is %d", sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `? :` ?

Comment: Look up `if` and the `<` operator.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :)) especially the ternary operator. I forgot that lol

Answer (score 4):

Using `if`

```
 if(num>0)
     sum+=num;
```

Another way using ternary operator `? :`

```
sum += num>0? num: 0;
```

Comment: In reality this is probably the best thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I know of is to use

`sum += 0 ^ ((0 ^ num) & -(0 < num))`

This uses the idiomatic way of computing `max`

`x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))`

for `int` types (which will be faster than either an `if` or a ternary.)

If speed is not of the essence and your C implementation has `max` (or `MAX`) then do consider using that instead: `sum += max(0, num)`

Comment: That is actually better if speed is essential. Gonna take note of this. Thank you very much :))

Comment: the question was to resolve something other than speed, you have to keep the complexity at the same level it is already.